# A piece of typescript is working as intended on my emulator but fails on Android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

The error that I receive in my Chrome: Inspect log is as below:

```
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function↵TypeError: undefined is not a function↵    at file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:101314:24↵    at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:11562)↵    at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:4403:37)↵    at t.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:11532)↵    at n.run (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:6468)↵    at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:3767↵    at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:12256)↵    at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:4394:37)↵    at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:12215)↵    at n.runTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:7153)↵    at a (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:2312)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13253)↵    at new Error (native)↵    at Error.d (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:3991)↵    at l (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:3244)↵    at file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:3798↵    at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:12256)↵    at Object.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:4394:37)↵    at t.invokeTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:12215)↵    at n.runTask (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:7153)↵    at a (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:2312)↵    at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (file:///android_asset/www/build/polyfills.js:3:13253)"
```

This happens when I try to run the following

```
(res) => {
        console.log(res);

        if (res.receiver) {
          ///Check if msisdn exists
          ///If it does, select that item
          var found = false;
          (<any>Object).values(this.approvedBenifs).forEach(element => {
            if (element.msisdn == res.receiver.FlashMsisdn) {
              this.selectedBenif = this.approvedBenifs.indexOf(element);
              found = true;
            }
          });
        }
```

However, running this code in Chrome through my Ionic emulator works fine.

The line that seems fishy to me is obviously the one involving `(<any>Object)`. Is the `(<any>Object).values()` method the problem here, and if so, what strategy *can* I use to get a collection of values from a specified array?

**Edit**

I've rewritten the code to be less weird, and it works:

```
  var found = false;

  for (let element of this.approvedBenifs) {
    if (element.msisdn == res.receiver.FlashMsisdn) {
      this.selectedBenif = this.approvedBenifs.indexOf(element);
      found = true;
    }
  }
```

However, I'd still be interested to know why the `(<any>Object).values()` method seems to fail on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try removing the

```
(<any>Object).values
```

(I'm asssuming this.approvedBenifs is an array) and just directly iterate through the array.

```
this.approvedBenifs.forEach(element => {
    if (element.msisdn == res.receiver.FlashMsisdn) {
        this.selectedBenif = this.approvedBenifs.indexOf(element);
        found = true;
    }
});
```

To get a collection of keys just use Object.keys(ARRAY_NAME) which will return an array of keys on the array or object. You're currently fetching the values.